# Creating an array by shifting values

Tags: python, numpy

I have an interger d and boolean array, say

```
M = array([[ True, False, False,  True],
           [False,  True, False, False],
           [False, False, False, False],
           [False, False, False,  True]])
```

Now I want to create a new array from M with the following rule: Trues stay and the next d positions left of a True also become True. I came up with this:

```
newarray = np.full_like(M,False)
  for r,row in enumerate(M[1:],1):
    for i,boo in enumerate(row):
      if boo:
        newarray[max(0,r-d):r,i] = True
```

I have the feeling there is a more efficient way of doing this using numpy commands; probably using np.where.

EDIT: e.g. d = 1, the result should be

```
M = array([[ True, False,  True,  True],
           [ True,  True, False, False],
           [False, False, False, False],
           [False, False,  True,  True]])
```

for  d = 2, the result should be

```
M = array([[ True,  True,  True,  True],
           [ True,  True, False, False],
           [False, False, False, False],
           [False,  True,  True,  True]])
```

Comment: How many True per row can you have? Exactly 1? More? Less?

Comment: Any number. Could be none, could be more. Made the example more elaborate to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for the update, then a 2D convolution should do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a 2D convolution with [`scipy.signal.convolve2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html):

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

d = 2

kernel = np.repeat([1, 1, 0], [d, 1, d])[None]
# array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])

out = convolve2d(M, kernel, mode='same') > 0
```

Output for `d = 1`:

```
array([[ True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True]])
```

Output for `d = 2`:

```
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @mozway, but with numpy's [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html) and [`pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

M = array([[ True, False, False,  True],
           [False,  True, False, False],
           [False, False, False, False],
           [False, False, False,  True]])

d = 2

out = swv(np.pad(M, ((0, 0), (0, d))), d + 1, axis=1).any(axis=2)
```

out:

```
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True]])
```

Comment: Yes, I was about to write something like this when the "convolution" approach ticked in my head ;)

Comment: Hehe, I had the same idea, but took a fair bit of trial and error to make it work. It's crazy that you are able to solve these and write an answer so quickly :)